# Depura muy detallado

Tags: netbeans

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo una pràctica en el que depuro el programa para mejor entendimiento. En mi otro(este) SO instalé Netbeans 8.2. Al depurar se supone NO debe depurar todo a profundidad, pero al llegar a esta parte:

```
System.out.println("1.-sumar");
```

me manda estos códigos de la imágen, y al seguir depurando(dàndole al botòn) me manda más y más còdigos. ¿còmo evito esto?

Comment: Durante el debug, usa la opción "Step Over"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza la tecla **F8** para depurar

Diferencias

Step Over (**F8**) Ejecuta una línea de código. Si la instrucción es una llamada a un método, ejecuta el método sin entrar dentro del código del método.

Step Into (**F7**) Ejecuta una línea de código. Si la instrucción es una llamada a un método, salta al método y continúa la ejecución por la primera línea del método.

Answer (score 1):

Imagino estas usando 
<kbd>F7</kbd> para depurar (debugging - Step into)
Lo que estas realizando es depurando incluso las funciones internas que usa tu código.

**Lo que necesitas es depurar únicamente el programa, para esto usa la tecla:** <kbd>F8</kbd> (Step over)

Answer (score 1):

Cuando eso me pasa lo que hago es que muevo el punto desde donde inicia la depuración. O vario la forma de depuración.

Con F7 el depurador "entre en" (step into) el código, en cambio con F8 provoca que el código "pase a lo siguiente (step over)".

F7 entrar en código muestra los entresijos de llamadas a funciones y profundizará en él cuando se realizan muchas llamadas de funciones que llaman a otras.

F8 Por otro lado, pasar a través de él ignora el funcionamiento interno de las llamadas a funciones y sólo se enfoca en el valor que retorna.

Si necesita depurar una función llamada por el programa utiliza la opción de "entrar en" (step into). F7

Pero si deseas depurar el programa actual utiliza la opción de "pasar a lo siguiente" (step over). F8

Usted puede alternar las teclas al momento de depurar, solo debe hacerlo en el momento adecuado al momento de hacerlo.